# Get the implicitly instantiated generic types in from an assembly?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm trying to use C# reflection to retrieve all the types from an assembly (let's say: from the "ExecutingAssembly"), I can retrieve all the *explicitly* defined types including the generic types I define in the assembly. But I don't seem to be able to retrieve the *implicitly* instantiated generic types (the concrete version).

For example, `var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();` this would retrieve all the *explicitly* defined types (classes, structs that are defined in this assembly, including the generic ones, such as `class MyGenericClass<T>`).

However, in the same assembly, I actually use `MyGenericClass<int>` as the *concrete* type in my code to actually instantiate *objects* (such as: `MyGenericClass<int> myObject;`), but this *concrete* `MyGenericClass<int>` type doesn't seem to be retrievable by the code above.

I'm wondering if any instantiated generated types are actually retrieveable from the assembly, so I may use that type to do some code generation work later.

If they are not retrievable, any design suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The concrete types aren't created until they're used. With the exception of some AOT scenarios, the runtime does not know that you're going to create a new `MyGenericClass<int>` until it actually hits code which references it.

Comment: "... I may use that type ..." - one of the points of the design of .NETs generics is that they have to work with any possible type allowed by their declared type constraints. You don't need someone else to have used a particular combination beforehand.

Comment: What *problem* are you actually trying to solve? *Why* do you need this information? What does "*some code generation work*" actually entail?

Comment: Can you show us an example of code that you wish to see the type info for?

Comment: And what information do you want to obtain if you have a `public static MyGenericClass<T> CreateMyGenericClass<T>() { return new MyGenericClass<T>(); }` method? You don't know what callers are going to pass in. Or worse, some `MakeGenericType()` reflection magic inside your code somewhere? The actual closed generic type will be created by the runtime, at runtime. You have an XY problem. As @canton says, state the actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: Remember that a generic type can be created with reflection too so there's no way of knowing what type it is until runtime.

Comment: The actual problem is a bit complex to entail, thus I collapsed the complex problem into this simple to explain question. The intention was basically to know if this was possible, and then how? or, as most of the comments have explained, this is actually impossible (as well as the reason why). Thus I actually have enough information to my question, and thus having enough knowledge to choose an alternative design, which when I encounter other issues, I may post another condensed question. So the answer is no, not possible. Thank you all!

Comment: @CodeCaster purely for the discussion's sake, when I actually use this function, I would write it like `var obj = CreateMyGenericClass<int>();`, then the compiler would have all the information about that an object of `MyGenericClass<int>` would be instantiated (when instantiating an object, you need a concrete type, right?) - so, while the compiler knows what concrete object to instantiate, it would be able to somehow record that information in the assembly - not saying it acutlly did, but I had the impression that it might.

Comment: Yeah or perhaps it's invoked by external code, or by reflection (for more fun using user input or otherwise external information like a database record).

Comment: Yeah, but if the actual generic instantiation was spelled out in code, the compiler would have that information to record, fair? (just saying :-))

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is based on the assembly’s *metadata*. What you seem to want would need to involve some kind of *source code* inspection to figure out all the concrete generic types created at runtime. Possible? Yes, the compiler does it, but not with reflection.

Comment: Not *always* possible - reflection in particular can make things hard to analyse.

Comment: @canton7 Oh yes, if the assembly is creating types through reflection then that wouldn’t be easy at all to track down. But my bet is that the OP is asking about explicitly typed generic types in the code. Not really sure why he needs this information though.

Comment: Reading this answer twice, the inspection is pretty close to my observation - key point: _the compiler should know_

Answer (score -1):

This is not what you're after but you could go a level deeper and get all methods of all types and collect all return types and the types of all arguments.

Just to be clear, this is nothing close to code analysis that your task requires. This just gives your a little bit more info.

Comment: If an answer is "*nothing close to code analysis that your task requires*", maybe it shouldn't be an answer? Perhaps it should be a comment.

Comment: Of course! If I gave the impression that this analyses the code, I failed, because it wasn't my intention :)

Comment: Do you think Eric L. will see this question and add an answer?

Comment: not my downvote either ;-) (I actually like to see a reason why an answer was downvoted, in general)